# Why iterating and modifying the each element in nested list results in some wrong output?

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested-lists

The immutable and mutable is causing problem.

I was trying to rotate the matrix by 90 degree clockwise without changing the argument passed in function.

```
def rotate(m):
    rm=[[0]*len(m)]*(len(m))
    print("m:",m)
    print("rm:",rm)
    for j in range(len(rm)):
        for i in range(len(rm)):
            k=m[j][i]
            y=(len(rm)-j-1)
            rm[i][y] = k
            print(i," ",len(rm)-j-1," ",rm[i][(len(rm)-j-1)])
    print("m:",m)
    print("rm:",rm)
    return rm

 print(rotate([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]))
```

I expect the rm should be "[[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]" but it is 
"[[9, 6, 3], [9, 6, 3], [9, 6, 3]]" at the end of function.

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing the error, because the line `rm=[[0]*len(m)]*(len(m))`. Try to change it for:

```
rm = [[0 for _ in range(len(m))] for _ in range(len(m))]
```

Note: The above function can be rewritten as:

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

def rotate(lst):
    return [list(val[::-1]) for val in zip(*lst)]

print(rotate(l))
```

This prints:

```
[[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
```

Comment: Wow. I think this is something that is important and non-obvious (maybe it is obvious  to everyone but me, I dunno). `rm1=[[0]*3]*3` (OPs approach) and `rm2=[[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]` (Andrej's approach) will produce lists `rm1` and `rm2` that look alike and compare equal, but behave differently. Assigning `rm1[0][0]=33` will result in list `[[33, 0, 0], [33, 0, 0], [33, 0, 0]]` whereas assigning `rm2[0][0]=44` will result in list `[[44, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]`.